# Using recursion to split text file based on delimiter in python

Tags: python, recursion

I have a plaintext file that I would like to split into multiple files. The file format is like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text1
text2
text3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text4
text5
text6
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text7
text8
text9
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text10
text11
text12
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to split each block from (and including) BEGIN to (and including) END.

This is what I have written so far:

```
with open('/Users/arl/Downloads/bundle.pem', 'r') as cert_file:
    cert = cert_file.readlines()

def parse_file(filename=None, variable=None):
    with open(filename, "w") as variable:
        for line in cert:
            if "BEGIN" in line:
                variable.write(line)
                continue
            elif "END" in line:
                variable.write(line)
                parse_file(filename="int1.pem", variable="int1_file")
                parse_file(filename="int2.pem", variable="int2_file")
                parse_file(filename="end.pem", variable="end_file")
            print line.rstrip()
            variable.write(line)
        variable.close()

parse_file(filename="root.pem", variable="root_file")
```

The error I currently get:

```
    parse_file(filename="int1.pem", variable="int1_file")
  File "splitter.py", line 12, in parse_file
    parse_file(filename="int1.pem", variable="int1_file")
  File "splitter.py", line 17, in parse_file
    variable.close()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

And only `root.pem` and `int1.pem` are written (and both have the same content, which they shouldn't)

What do I need to do in order to parse over the file and write each new block to a new file? Which is the right point in the loop to for the function to call itself with the new parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Your function only actually reads from the global file (cert), so your recursive calls simply make it read from that file again and again, hence the infinite recursion.

Comment: Not at all clear what you're trying to do and why you want to use recursion. Also, you overwrite `variable` with the file pointer, so that parameter will have no effect. Do you want root.pem, int1.pem, int2.pem and end.pem each to contain one section from bundle.pem?

Comment: @AlanLeuthard: Yes, I see that now. I'm trying to figure out how to continue reading from where I last finished instead of starting from the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Stuart yes thats exactly what I am trying to do. I'm not at all sure if recursion is what is needed, or just some kind of nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see that recursion would be useful here - instead you could make a list of the output file names and iterate through them using `iter` and `next`, to open a file when you encounter "BEGIN", then close the same file when you encounter "END".

```
def parse_file(input_file, output_files):
    filenames = iter(output_files)
    with open(input_file, 'r') as cert_file:
        for line in cert_file:
            if "BEGIN" in line:
                output = open(filenames.next(), 'w')
            output.write(line)
            if "END" in line:
                output.close()
    output.close() # just in case not already closed

input_file = '/Users/arl/Downloads/bundle.pem'
output_files = ['root.pem', 'int1.pem', 'int2.pem', 'end.pem']
parse_file(input_file=input_file, output_files=output_files)
```

This will raise an error if there is any space or other content in between 'BEGIN' and 'END'. If that is a problem you could add a line to check that the output file has been opened.

```
def parse_file(input_file, output_files):
    filenames = iter(output_files)
    output = None
    with open(input_file, 'r') as cert_file:
        for line in cert_file:
            if "BEGIN" in line:
                output = open(filenames.next(), 'w')
            if output and not output.closed:
                output.write(line)
            if "END" in line:
                output.close()
    output.close()
```

Or equivalently, use a nested loop:

```
def parse_file(input_file, output_files):
    output = None
    with open(input_file, 'r') as cert_file:
        for output_file in output_files:
            for line in cert_file:
                if "BEGIN" in line:
                    output = open(output_file, 'w')
                if output and not output.closed:
                    output.write(line)
                if "END" in line:
                    output.close()
                    break  # breaks out of inner loop and gets next output_file
    output.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Via regular expressions:

```
import re

content = '''
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text1
text2
text3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text4
text5
text6
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text7
text8
text9
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text10
text11
text12
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
'''

content = content.strip('\n')

pattern = re.compile('\-\-\-\-\-BEGIN CERTIFICATE\-\-\-\-\-((.|\n)*?)\-\-\-\-\-END CERTIFICATE\-\-\-\-\-')
certs = re.findall(pattern, content)
for cert in certs:  
    cert_content = cert[0].strip('\n')
    print cert_content
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer but allows for more segments between BEGIN and END without requiring you to list the names of files manually. The script renames the final file it outputs. No need for recursion, as others have mentioned. (Recursion will make you insane.)

```
collect = False
file_number = -1
with open('big_file.txt') as big:
    for line in big.readlines():
        if line.startswith('-----BEGIN'):
            collect = True
            file_number += 1
            little = open('int%s.pem' % file_number, 'w')
            continue
        elif line.startswith('-----END'):
            little.close()
            collect = False
        else:
            little.write(line)

import os
os.rename('int%s.pem' % file_number, 'end.pem')
```